# Angular material stepper index

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

am having a problem on changing a class once i click on the step of a mat-stepper.
Does anybody knows how to give a dynamic class once the stepper change index for example ?

Comment: Could you please explain a little more? What element are you changing the class on? Do you want it to change based on the step that is selected?

Comment: @robbieAreBest exactly, i'd like to change the class, for example the background color, lets say of the step number, based on the selected step.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried before and whats not working as per your expectation ?

Comment: I am trying to edit the background of my step-header using a custom class, with the selected item property.
Point 1: it works when i try to modify html elements.
Point 2: it doesn't work, because the step-header is generated automatically from  the mat-stepper.

So my question is, how can i give a custom class, on the selected step to its step-header ?

Hope it will help a bit ! @GaurangDhorda

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gagypxjnadb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts take this example, and tell me whats are you doing and not working ?

Comment: here is the example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agv7m3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-overview-example.html.
What i'd like to do, is to change the background of the entire step-header, the one you see when you hover the place "Fill out your name" for example. @GaurangDhorda

Comment: Means you need to change backgroundColor of part where you click on 1 stepper, then some animation effects takes place, and you want to change color of that part only but when its selected stepper ?

Comment: Whe we click the step 1 for example, the "container" of Fill out your name, become red for example. 
For "container" i mean, the entire area u see when you hover the step.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Yep, that's the point.

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

I've got this solution working for me,it was easier then i thought, hope it will helps someone :

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-step-header[aria-selected="true"]  {
      background-color: var(--primary-color);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here a demo on stackblitz, it changes the background of the step icon once you click on the stepper.

[stepper dynamic change](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fetocv?file=src/styles.scss)